# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm encountering an issue while developing a React application where I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')". This error occurs when I attempt to perform the 'push' operation on an object that is undefined. I've checked my code, and it seems that the variable I'm trying to 'push' onto is initialized correctly, so I'm puzzled about what could be causing the problem.

**React code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Badge,
  Button,
  Col,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  Row,
  Table,
  UncontrolledButtonDropdown,
} from 'reactstrap';
import Widget from '../../../components/Widget';
import s from './Static.module.scss';
import { newUser, ricercaclienti } from '../../../services/cliente';

class Static extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.textInput = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      tableStyles: [],
      input: '',
    };

    this.handleChangetext = this.handleChangetext.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
  }

  getEventEditUser(
    id,
    ragioneSociale,
    indirizzo,
    provincia,
    partitaiva,
    CodiceFiscale,
    titolo,
    fax,
    pec,
    Dirittochiamata,
    sdi,
    RimborsoKM,
    citta,
    cap,
    Telefono,
    Email,
    Nome1,
    Nome2,
    Cellulare1,
    Cellulare2,
    Sconto1,
    Sconto2,
    Sconto3,
    IBAN,
    Applicaprezzorisorsegiornaliero
  ) {
    localStorage.setItem('IdClienteSelect', id);
    localStorage.setItem('RagioneSocialeSelect', ragioneSociale);
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/app/editclient',
      state: {
        idCliente: id,
        ragioneSociale: ragioneSociale,
        indirizzo: indirizzo,
        Provincia: provincia,
        PartitaIVA: partitaiva,
        CodiceFiscale: CodiceFiscale,
        Titolo: titolo,
        FAX: fax,
        PEC: pec,
        Dirittochiamata: Dirittochiamata,
        SDI: sdi,
        RimborsoKM: RimborsoKM,
        Citta: citta,
        Cap: cap,
        Telefono: Telefono,
        Email: Email,
        Nome1: Nome1,
        Cellulare1: Cellulare1,
        Nome2: Nome2,
        Cellulare2: Cellulare2,
        Sconto1: Sconto1,
        Sconto2: Sconto2,
        Sconto3: Sconto3,
        IBAN: IBAN,
        Applicaprezzorisorsegiornaliero: Applicaprezzorisorsegiornaliero,
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Because there is no ```this.props.history```.
If you call ```console.log(this.props)``` in the ```getEventEditUser``` method, will ```this.props.history``` be checked?

Answer (score -1):

you can just add the nullable check "?" like this:

```js
this.props?.history?.push({})
```

Comment: not open page ...